# Recuperar objeto array padronizado

Tags: javascript, array

Olá, a todos. Estou com um problema para recuperar um objeto, segue a minha situação:

**Como estou fazendo:**

```
$scope.data = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $scope.data.push(i);
}
```

//Resultado: [0,1,2,3,4]

**Resultado que eu preciso**

[[0,1,2,3,4]]

O que eu preciso e montar um gráfico com a biblioteca Charts.js porem os dados vem de uma consulta e não estou conseguindo montar este objeto neste formato. 
(Obs: no eu projeto utilizo angular.js)

Agradeço a atenção de todos

Comment: Testa assim: https://jsfiddle.net/y9p0xbu4/, era isso que precisas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o que precisas é inserir arrays dentro desse `$scope.data` então quando fazes `$scope.data.push(algo);` esse `algo` tem de ser uma array.

Podes resolver isso assim:

```
var _data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    _data.push(i);
}
$scope.data.push(_data);
```

Comment: Olha só...  cara era isso mesmo deu certinho aqui. muito obrigado amigo!!